# UWP - In App Tutorial Grey Out All But One Xaml Element

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp

Example http://dashboard.securingdemocracy.org/ going to that page and clicking the 'First Time: Click Here' button will start a brief tutorial. I want to replicate this in my UWP application. I am unsure how to replicate the dimming effect. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the light dismiss dialog you may try to use [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout) control in UWP.

For the mask effects,if you just want a simple implementation, you may try to use a shape with `Opacity` setting to cover the UI controls which will have the mask effects on the controls, and setting the `Canvas.Index` attached property to control the z-order for one control that will not be covered.  For example:

```
<Canvas Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <TextBox Text="Testparagraph" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Background="White" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
   <TextBox Text="testparagraph 2"  Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="20"  Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Background="White" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
   <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" Height="400" Width="400" Canvas.ZIndex="0"></Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

For a complex and better implementation please try to use [Composition effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-effects). There're some samples of the mask effects in the [`WindowsUIDevLabs`](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs) library. For example, mask effect of [ForegroundFocusEffects](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ForegroundFocusEffects). Details for your scenario please try to implement by yourself.